# libpq VS qpsql(QT driver for postgre)

Tags: c++, c, database, qt, libpq

I've been working with QT 4.8 and QT Postgresql driver in order to make a Postgresql connection header and a class, and when I finally done with it my boss tolds me to forget it and re-make it in the native libpq... He uses QT as the ide in where the program which will use the header resides and I know, programmatically, it's not a good idea combining paradigms but well...I'm doing as he says. So! the real question I wanna know is...What are the main diffences about using those two? (aside of one being c and the other c++)

I mean, in terms of efficiency, performance and size of the programs as well as the types of data? Also if it may be changes in the connection done to the database. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the postgres interface of Qt `./src/sql/drivers/psql/qsql_psql.cpp` (Qt 4.4.3) reveals that is built on top of `libpq`, so it is unlikely there are considerable performance differences.

In defense of your boss: by building on top of `libpq` the GUI part can be separated from the core of the application, allowing for example batch processing. On the other hand it must be said that a Qt application can also be run in batch. Your boss may however be worried about relying on the future developments of Qt.

Comment: mmmm, I was thinking of something alike and not, my boss just told me to use libpq cause he does not want to "waste time" installing qt and it's driver but in first time he told we was going to develop using qt...
But, aside of that, thanks! I was having that thought for around two weeks